# How to get current working directory in GWT Java

Tags: java, gwt, working-directory

I'm using Java 1.6 with GWT 2.4.

I'm very well aware that we can get current working directory in Java using the following code:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

But GWT won't allow me to use System class at client side.

So my question is: Is there any way to get the current working directory path in GWT?

Comment: i am curious to know, why you require this ?

Comment: Can you mention the what you intend to achieve with this data. We can provide suggestion based on that.

Comment: @zzzz, Thanks for replying but that question is for current URL in browser. I'm asking for current directory...

Comment: @ajduke My requirement is, I need to show an image on my app dashboard. I'm deploying the app in Jboss 7.1. The path of the image would be like \jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\files\1.png. So in coding how should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new  service (in your `RemoteService/RemoteServiceImpl`) which will basically get the current working directory using `System.getProperty("user.dir");` ?

Its a work-around, cause GWT (client) code doesn't have javascript replacement for `java.lang.System` class OR i guess they don't have previlidge to read System properties (since they run on browser)

Answer (score 0):

1. You would need to use [RPC](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls) call or [RequestBuilder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests) call.
2. Pass the parameter the image name to the server
3. In the service class on server side calculate the system path and return back the path information.

GWT compiles to javascript and is executed in the browser communicating with a server over http and hence cannot execute server side java code like `System.getProperty("user.dir");` .

***Any such requirement should be achieved via [Asynchronous](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication) call to the Server.***

**Note:** It still does not make sense to display the file system path to the user unless you are writing a System Explorer with Web GUI ( might raise some security related queries !!!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not showing file system path to the User. Can you tell why do you think so?

Comment: I could not think of any other need on the client side to show file system path. Even for downloading the image for the user in browser it just requires relative path from webapp context. I am curious now as to why on your side of the requirement :)

Comment: Got it. You are hosting your image files in non-webapp context i.e not in the war deploying your GWT. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

```
Current Directory in GWT.
```

your all java script in on client side so,there is no matter of `current directory`.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Due to security reasons `javascript` doesn't have access to the system drives to avoid **syber attacks**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

see [Opening a file in local file system in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534297/opening-a-file-in-local-file-system-in-javascript)

Inorder to get the file you need to make a server call.

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("user.dir") worked for me fine in GWT 2.6.1, both when running locally and when deployed to Google App Engine (where it returned e.g. /base/data/home/apps/s~rhezivt28/1.379778380561169345).