# How to open a file location in my PC using javascript for Apps for office 2013?

Tags: apps-for-office

I have created an Task pane app for office 2013 in excel. It has few buttons and labels.
Now I want to open a file location on my PC on clicking of the button. So please tell me the code for it as I'm new to java-script.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534297/opening-a-file-in-local-file-system-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no existing openFile API in JavaScript for Office, but you can use ajax to call wcf to get string from existing document and use Document.setSelectedDataAsync method to write the got string to the document.