# window.open opens up a blank page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a local html file

```
window.open("file:///C:/Users/somepath/www/index.html", "", "width=500, height=500");
```

But this ends up in opening a blank page

(the html file exists in that path)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j0qc3exL/)

Comment: Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534297/opening-a-file-in-local-file-system-in-javascript

Comment: host the app and try to access using http

Comment: I just want to point out that you mention the D drive, and the path in your JSFIDDLE also points to a file in the D drive, while the code you've embedded in the question references a path in the C drive. [edit: this is not the source of your problem]

Comment: @Kumar thanks for the link

Comment: @CafeCoder looks like its not allowed to open local file from a file hosted over internet

Comment: downvoters care to drop a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons both html files **must** to be in the same domain. A html file in *the cloud* can't open a local html file.